# Include empty EDIFACT segment in BizTalk with separators

Tags: xslt, biztalk, biztalk-2010, edi, edifact

One of our trading partners requires an `IMD+F` segment per item in their EDI invoice, even if it's empty. They want it to look like this:

```
IMD+F++:::'
```

In the XSLT that maps to the EDIFACT (D96A) Invoice, I have the following:

```
<ns0:IMD_2>
  <IMD01>F</IMD01>
  <IMD02></IMD02>
  <ns0:C273_2>
    <C27301></C27301>
    <C27302></C27302>
    <C27303></C27303>
    <C27304> </C27304>
  </ns0:C273_2>
</ns0:IMD_2>
```

Notice the space in the `C27304` segment. BizTalk assembles this into the following EDI:

```
IMD+F'
```

How can I get the full segment with separators?

Comment: well, maybe the easiest way out is to provide a description? Most cases there is a description...

Answer (score 0):

On the Validation section of the YOU->THEM tab of the Agreement, you can adjust the Leading & Trailing Spaces and Trailing Separator values.

Comment: That didn't help, unfortunately. I tried setting it both to optional and mandatory and restarted the host instance.

Answer (score 0):

Space is considered a character, thus you should able to get this

'IMD+F++::: ' segment based on

```
    <ns0:IMD_2>
  <IMD01>F</IMD01>
  <IMD02></IMD02>
  <ns0:C273_2>
    <C27301></C27301>
    <C27302></C27302>
    <C27303></C27303>
    <C27304> </C27304>
  </ns0:C273_2>
</ns0:IMD_2>
```

If you are using any maps, make sure to remove these empty spaces.

Comment: You just copied the code from my question... or what am I missing?

Comment: Based on your sample xml there's space on node C27304. So it should generate 'IMD+F++::: ' not 'IMD+F'

Comment: Well tough luck because that's what it was doing. I wouldn't create a question if it was working would I?